# Can IntelliJ warn when Kotlin API is not callable from Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

Consider the following code:

```kotlin
class Foo {
    inline fun <reified T> bar() { ... }
}
```

**The `bar` method above is not callable from Java!**

In most cases there are workarounds to create Java compatible APIs, but you have to know what they are and when to apply them. Without that knowledge, you might be oblivious to the fact that certain APIs just wont be compatible.

Does IntelliJ offer any facility to warn when APIs are not Java compatible, or better still, suggest how to make them compatible?

Comment: I don't know of any such tool in IntelliJ, but I believe there are a very few cases like this. `reified`, suspend functions (they are available, but are very hard to invoke), ... nothing else come to my mind.

Comment: Also class/method/field names which aren't legal Java identifiers (e.g. are Java keywords, or contain invalid characters). (Fixable by annotation.)

Comment: @broot I don't think operator functions are callable by Java either, but I may be wrong. Possibly in Java, you just call the function itself, rather than using an operator.

Comment: Operators are just regular functions, only with a syntactic sugar to invoke them with a special syntax. We can still call them by name from both Kotlin and Java.

Comment: If it is an absolute necessity, you can code to create a custom `Detekt` rule like "NotCallableFromJava". https://detekt.dev/docs/introduction/extensions/